# Show that $S^n \times R$ is parallelizable for all n

Tags: differential-topology

A manifold $M^n$ is called parallelizable if and only if there exist n vector fields on $M^n$ which are independent at each point of $M^n$. Could you help me figure out the vector fields for $S^n \times R$?

Comment: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes **your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it**. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider  $f:S^n\times \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n+1}-\{0\}$ defined by $f(x,t)=e^tx$, it is a diffeomorphism where you identify $S^n $ with the unit sphere of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}-\{0\}$;  $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}-\{0\}$ is parallelizable since it is an open subset of  $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.